# How can I force PDB to quit when the signal is being caught?

Tags: python, pdb

PDB's quit command works by raising an exception (`Bdb.BdbQuit`). If that exception gets caught, I cannot figure out a way to kill the program short of killing the entire shell. CTRL+C works by raising a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, which can also be caught.

You can recreate this problem with this simple script.

```py
foo = 0
while True:
    try:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        foo += 1
    except:
        pass
```

This script **cannot be stopped** from within PDB with the quit command or CTRL+C.

I'm aware this is bad programming and you should never use an `except` without an exception type. I ask because I ran into this issue while debugging and a third-party library trapped me in the loop.

Comment: This is an unsolvable problem, of course.  The whole reason we have SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT and SIGKILL is that, every time someone invented a way to block a kill signal, someone else invented an unkillable signal.  If you are on Linux, you can try Ctrl-\ .  Otherwise, you'll need to Ctrl-Z and kill the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try killing the python process with [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit).

```py
import os
try:
    print("Exiting")
    os._exit(1)
except:
    print("Caught!")
```

Output:

```
Exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not re-raise the exception:

```py
import bdb

try: 
   something_i_might_want_to_debug_with_pdb()
except bdb.BdbQuit as exc:
   raise exc
except:
    print("Caught!")
```